# Is it possible to trace MorphologicalTransform?

Tags: image-processing, debugging

Is there a way to see the arguments supplied to a function specified as second argument of `MorphologicalTransform`?

An approach with `Echo` (or `Print`) prints something strange and **at the first evaluation only**:

```
i = Image[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}];

MorphologicalTransform[Binarize@i, Echo[#][[2, 2]] &]
```

[image: output]

Obviously there must be only `3×3` = `9` arguments supplied in this case. Why we get so many prints which apparently **do not reflect the actual contents of the image**? And the main question: how to obtain all the arguments supplied to the transformation function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output shown in the question is a faithful representation of the arguments actually passed to the function.  `MorphologicalTransform` converts the function into a lookup table by computing the results of applying the function to all 512 possible 3x3 binary matrices.  The resulting lookup table is then added to a cache stored under the symbol `` Image`MorphologicalOperationsDump`cashedrules `` [*sic*]:

```
Image`MorphologicalOperationsDump`cashedrules
```

[image: lookup table cache]

This cache permits faster transformation operations but also imposes the restriction that the function must be deterministic and free of side-effects.  Subsequent uses of `MorphologicalTransform` with the same function use the cached lookup table instead of evaluating the function again.

I am not aware of any way to clear the cache short of manually updating the cache variable.

The code that generates the lookup table can be inspected by evaluating:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Image`MorphologicalOperationsDump`convertFuncToLUT]
```

This analysis is current as of *Mathematica* version 11.2.0.

Answer (score 5):

So I don't think it takes any arguments other than some form of "current" neighborhood or whatever.

Here's a way to investigate this:

```
Remove[args];
args = {};
MorphologicalTransform[Binarize@i, 
 Set[args, {args, {##}}][[2, 1, 1, 1]] &]
```

The `Remove` just makes it work every time

Then you can look at the neighborhoods it tests like so:

```
tests = Table[
   args[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, d], 2, 1]],
   {d, Depth[args] - 5, 1, -1}
   ] // Map[Image]
```

Here's a subsample of them:

```
Take[tests, 25] // Partition[#, 5] & // GraphicsGrid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image: huh]

I won't lie, I'm not exactly sure what it means, but it's what's being passed.

Comment: Here's what I did: `{res, int} = Reap[MorphologicalTransform[Binarize @ i, With[{args = {##}}, Sow[Image[args[[1]]]]; args[[1, 2, 2]]] &]]; ListAnimate[int[[1]]]` to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn8X7.gif).

Comment: Nice trick with `Remove`! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Some other observations adding on to b3m2a1's answer.

It appears that no matter the size of the image, the number of "args" that get passed to the function is $2^9=512$ (the number of $3\times3$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$):

```
n = 4;
m = 6;

i = Image@Table[RandomInteger[], {rows, n}, {cols, m}];

Remove[args];
args = {};
MorphologicalTransform[
 Binarize@i, (AppendTo[args, #]; 
   Max@#) &]; (*The Max part is not really important, just chose it \
randomly*)

Length@args (*This is always 2^9 = 512*)
```

I'm also not too sure what's going on here, but if I had to guess, I'd say `MorphologicalTransform` is building up a "cache" of the image (here I mean the math kind of image) of the function you're supplying by applying it to all the possible $3\times3$ neighborhoods.

Again, I don't really know what's supposed to be happening here, just speculating, mostly.